# Why is this question off-topic?

Tags: discussion, support

I was looking at this question which is historic but massively upvoted, and I don't understand why it's off topic.

[Does orientation affect hard drive lifespan?](https://serverfault.com/q/13839/18822)

Mounting hard drives would seem to be very much on topic here,https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic

> If your question is about:
>
> managing the hardware or software of servers, workstations, storage or networks

I don't see any indication that anything about that question is prohibited or that the question is otherwise unclear.

Moreover, the question doesn't even seem basic to me: do drives having dampening mechanisms that require a specific orientation? Does drive orientation affect heat dissipation? etc. etc.

Answer (score 3):

I think the question is arguably off-topic since it's more about hardware design than system administration.

But I would guess that the question is locked because it was getting low-quality answers a few years after it was asked.  I think the text of the lock message is standard, so it might not apply perfectly to this situation.

Comment: I have no objection to it being locked, but i can't upvote it and as a policy, I like to upvote any question that address what Google sent me here looking for. Perhaps what ever was intended by locking, that's the wrong functionality. Unless you don't want me to send the message to the person asking the question that it was good question and one that I was also curious about.